# In the UK, what provisions exist for MPs to be temporarily replaced due to illness or parental leave?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

Suppose that an MP is temporarily unable to perform their duties, such as during illness or paternity.  Can the MP assign a replacement to perform their role in parliament until they are able to work again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [September 2020](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2020-09-23/debates/C3AA197A-A1CD-49BB-B6E2-49E920F58853/ProxyVoting), provisions have been in place via [Standing Order 39A](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm5802/cmstords/so_804_2021/so-804_02122021v2.pdf) of the House of Commons for MPs to cast proxy votes when they are unable to attend divisions because of parental leave.

In [October 2022](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2022-10-12/debates/C7D486BC-7EF7-4AF5-8712-BA916FD56EA6/VotingByProxy(AmendmentAndExtension)), these provisions were clarified, expanding the parental leave category to childbirth, care of an infant or newly adopted child, or complications relating to childbirth, miscarriage or baby loss. A pilot scheme running until April 2023 also allows MPs unable to attend the House because of serious long-term injury or illness to cast a proxy vote.

The current (updated October 2022) Proxy Voting Scheme as published by the Speaker is [available here](https://www.parliament.uk/globalassets/globalassets/proxyvotingscheme13oct2022.pdf).

While provisions exist for the casting of proxy votes in the circumstances above, there are no provisions for an MP to be temporarily replaced in, for example, debates, during their leave of absence from the House.

Answer (score 6):

There is certainly no provision for anyone other than the elected MP to take his or her seat in the House of Commons.

So far as voting is concerned, there have been occasions, at the time of critical votes, where MPs have been ferried in in ambulances. But usually, in circumstances like that, rather than have ambulances brought on to the Parliamentary estate, an MP intending to vote in an opposing lobby will "pair" with the sick MP. (A "pair" is a gentleman's (or lady's) agreement made between MPs of opposing parties not to vote if the other one doesn't. They are arranged by the respective whips' offices.)

As far as general constituency business is concerned, the MP's staff will tend to cover periods of sickness, and if necessary a fellow MP of the same party can help out with parliamentary business. At least that is how I feel sure it works.

Answer (score 3):

Unless things have changed since 2014 and I missed it, only an MP herself is allowed to debate matters in the commons, or vote at a division. In order to vote an MP must be "in the building", but the concept of '[nodding through](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-28127157)' exists to mean that the MP doesn't necessarily have to pass through the relevant lobby to get her vote recorded. At various occasions in the past this has [allegedly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_of_the_assembly#Nodding_through) involved attempts to arrange ambulances to deliver and collect critically ill MPs from the parliamentary estate.